# Parse.com - exporting ordered data from

Tags: parse-platform

I have a class in my Parse.com project.

I can export it in JSON to my email.

But it seems that the JSON is ordered by objectId. (00qABGfFGt, 01Qs4oK2Us, ...)

Can I export it so it would be ordered by, for example, "createdAt" value?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the JSON to CSV

Create a spreadsheet using that CSV using Libre Office, Microsoft Office, Google Sheets, Numbers, or whatever else is your spreadsheet software of choice.

Sort however you want

Export to CSV

Convert to JSON

Comment: how do I export in CSV?

Comment: you can't, you need to convert

Comment: Exporting is only in JSON. But you can just google "convert JSON to CSV" to find some free online tools, and then the CSV can be read by any spreadsheet software, which should have a sorting method. You can export again as CSV, and convert that back to JSON probably using the same tool you used to convert the JSON to CSV.